# Setup http response header for cache control on gitlab pages

Tags: http-headers, cache-control, response-headers, gitlab-pages

I have uploaded a pwa on gitlab pages. I want to know to setup http response headers on gitlab pages to setup cache control. I've done my best searching for this info on the internet in general and on this site as well. I only found an entry from 2017 that said this wasn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

[This note](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-pages/issues/50#note_204369273) on Issue #50 seems to indicate that you can set headers globally for all the pages